# download multiple files on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops, download, nsurlconnection

i want to download file(s) from web server.

Scenario:
As user will select row (file name- user can select 1 or more files to download) and and press download, i am getting URL for each file(all have different URL) and storing into pathArray.
and doing following

```
-(void)downloadFile    {  
    for (int i = 0; i<[pathArray count]; i++) {    
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[pathArray objectAtIndex:i]];  

        NSString *ResultURL = [fileURL absoluteString];  
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:ResultURL];   
        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url   
        cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval: 60.0];   
        conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];  

        if (conn)   {
          NSLog(@"*************CONNECTED************");  
          webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];  
          NSLog(@"weblength : %d : ", [webData length]);  
          downloadTag = YES;  
        } else {
            NSLog(@"*************Connection NOT DONE************");  
            downloadTag=NO;  
        }  
    }  
}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  {  
    NSLog(@"*************Try to receive data************");  
    [webData appendData:data];  
    NSLog(@"weblength : %d : ", [webData length]);  
    NSLog(@"*************Data Received an append too ***********");  
    if (downloadTag == YES)  {  
        paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDir = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewResult.zip" ];  
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentsDir contents:nil attributes:nil];  
        NSFileHandle *file1 = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: documentsDir];  
        [file1 writeData: webData];  
        NSLog(@"Webdata : %d",[webData length]);  
        [file1 closeFile];  
    }  
}
```

if i am not using for loop i.e only one file download then it work fine but not with for loop....its really important for me to solve this issue.

thank you very much

Comment: The only I could say is that in your current loop you are going to send several asynchronous requests but gathering data in a single array... Unless I am missing something it will not work.

Comment: @MiKL, what should I do then..please explain me little bit more...i am very much confused.thanks

Comment: You could always use a `NSURLConnection` to download information such as to where a file is stored and then download it using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)]`. To download on separate threads you can use a `NSAutoreleasePool` and then call the `NSData` method.

Comment: will check for NSAutoreleasePool, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using asynchronous downloads, but the delegate for each download item is the same object, causing all of the downloaded data to get appended to the same file. The way I do it is to have a small Object (DownloadQueueItem) that is the delegate for a single download. When you download another file, you create a new DownloadQueueItem and it handles everything.

---

Edit:

**Q:** *instead of %i putting by my self i am searching is there any way to create new file every time like if ""NewResult.zip" is exist then create "NewResult1.zip" and so on*

**A:** You could do something like this:

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"NewResult%@.zip";
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    NSString *filename = NULL;

    if (i == 0) {
        filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:filename, @""];
    }
    else {
        filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:filename, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    }

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filename]) {
        // Save file.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i try to use synchronous and its work fine but now only issue is its overwrite to my existing file, now i have to search how to create new file every time without overwrite old one

Comment: i am using,  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
documentsDir = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewResult.zip" ];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentsDir contents:nil attributes:nil];
NSFileHandle *file1 = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: documentsDir];
so for every encounter it should create"NewResult1.zip","NewResult2.zip"...and so on

Comment: Your logic is right, but I don't think your code is doing what you're telling me. It looks like it's only using a single file for saving. You need to do something more like: `documentsDir = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NewResult%i.zip", counter]];` Where counter is a the download number of the file.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer, instead of %i putting by my self i am searching is there any way to create new file every time like if ""NewResult.zip" is exist then create "NewResult1.zip" and so on

Answer (score 2):

take a look at ASIHTTPRequest, it has a nice queue for downloading and monitoring progress http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use